# Magento 2: Get Table Rate Amount programmatically

Tags: magento2, php, shipping

We have a Magento 2 shop with 15 subshops (for regional purposes) with several currencies.

Each subshop has a different table rate setting. Mostly consisting of two values e.g. 10 Euro shipping. 0 Euro if total above 350 Euro.

I want to program a block where I can get the amount where the shipping total is zero - so free shipping.

Since Magento 2 is overenginered I have no clue how this is possible.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Is there any objection to using the Free Shipping Method, with the minimum order amount enabled and set to 350 Euro?

Comment: The problem with that is, that you end up with two shipping options in the checkout. I could also simply use the 350 as value but when you have 15 subshops with each different free shipping values, and the free shipping amount changes, you don't want to manually update everything

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn’t want a second shipping method to display then I’d recommend creating a cart rule, where the discount is 100% and apply to shipping is turned on.  The action would be price in cart is equal to or over 350.  This coupon would be set to. “No Coupon”.

This should give you your desired result.  Hope this helps.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the misunderstanding.

The reason why I asked was, I want to program something like a progress bar to show the customer how much is needed to get free shipping based on the table rate values where the price is 0.

Since the price differs from subshop to subshop I want to retrieve this value directly.